# QProgressDialog cancel button sometimes not responsive

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am running a processor heavy operation and using a QProgressDialog to report back to the user. However, the cancel button works erratically - sometimes it is ignored for the entire run and sometimes it responds, but only after a certain point in the progress (this point is not consistent either). It seems to me as if the event loop is not being called, so I've put in a call to QApplication.instance().processEvents() but the erratic behaviour remains.

Here is the function doing the work.

```
def import(self):

    imp = worker()
    imp.progressChanged.connect(self.setImportProgress)
    self.progress.canceled.connect(imp.cancel)

    imp.run()

    self.progress.setValue(100) #Ensures we reach the end, in case of rounding errors

@Slot(int)
def setImportProgress(self,p):
    self.progress.setValue(p)
    QApplication.instance().processEvents()
```

Here is the worker's run class and cancel slot.

```
def run(self):
    frameCount = 0
    hundredth = self.numFrames/100 #Used to output percentages
    while True:
        ret, frame = self.cam.read()
        if not ret: #Breaks when the last frame is reached
            break
        if frameCount >= self.start:
            self.doWorkOnFrame()

            #Output the percentage completed
            if frameCount % hundredth == 0:
                self.progressChanged.emit(frameCount/hundredth)

@QtCore.Slot()
def cancel(self):
    print "Cancel Pressed"
```

I realize that the cancel slot does not do anything at the moment, I'm just trying to get it to activate consistently before I implement the actual functionality. I do get the "Cancel Pressed" output so I know the signal-slot connection is set up properly, it just isn't consistent when I press the button.

I realize there are similar questions to this, but I can't find the exact same problem nor do the solutions to similar problems seem to work. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Edit - Upon reading about a [similar problem](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/pyside/2012-August/000613.html) elsewhere, I wrote `QApplication.instance().processEvents()` 10 times in a row, and this solves the problem. Not exactly a pleasant solution - is there a limit on how many events are processed in one go?

Comment: According to the docs, calling `processEvents` with no arguments should process _all_ pending events for the calling thread. So on the face of it, your solution doesn't make much sense (i.e. there must be something else going on). BTW, do you have a link for the "similiar solution elsewhere"?

Comment: It was only similar in the sense that someone was asking why events weren't being processed and the reply said to try the call several times, but I've added the link to my post. But I certainly agree - it doesn't make sense.

I've found a slightly more elegant solution is calling setImportProgress every frame, instead of every 1%. That solves the problem - so it still seems to be a matter of calling processEvents() more often. 1% is roughly 20 frames, and I found at 10 frames the cancel button worked more often but still not all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the link. So it looks like a bug (as I was beginning to suspect). Have you tried with PyQt?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have PyQT available on this machine. The discussion in the link suggests that the problem (or at least a related one) does persist in PyQT, but I'm unable to check. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not updating the GUI often enough for the cancel button to work properly.

Calling `QApplication.instance().processEvents()` is the right thing to do, but *definitely not* from within the worker thread. It needs to be called from within the GUI thread (i.e. in the `setImportProgress` signal handler).

The question is: how long does it take to process 1 percent of the frames? Because the progress dialog is going to be unresponsive during this period of time. You need to find a more appropriate step value for emitting the `progressChanged` signal - one that is short enough to keep the cancel button responsive, but not so short that it impacts overall performance.

Comment: Processing 1% of the frames tends to take somewhere around 1/2 a second, which I think is good enough for this purpose. However, I've moved my processEvents() call to setImportProgress (I'll update the question to show the code) and my problem persists. The update does not come in 1/2 a second, sometimes it appears randomly and sometimes at the very end I see all the "Cancel Pressed" messages at once.